# Jquery Validation validate form-array with index

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to validate the floor fields that mention below.

```
<form id="test_form" >
<input name="floor[abc]" type="text" class="input_txt_l " value="" />
<input name="floor[cde]" type="text" class="input_txt_l " value="" />
</form>
```

I tried with jquery validator plug-in.

```
jQuery("#test_form").validate({
    rules: {
    'floor[]':{
        required:true
    }},
messages: {
        'floor[]':{
            required:"floor is required."
            }
     }
    });
```

In here validation is not working. but if the floor has no index , It works well. If someone have idea to fix this issue please help me.

Comment: try changing name=floor[] on both the input fields.
What you might want is do have same validation for all the floor.

Comment: @axel.michel I have looked this. but with `floor[index]` it doesn't work.

Comment: @Anshul Nigam It can't change as floor[], Need index for floor

Comment: then use like floor[][ID]

Comment: What is your exact requirement, why do you need index?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/7ox4r01s/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to solve your problem:

Either you use `addClassRules`:

```
// using the class name instead of field name
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("input_txt_l", {
    required: true       
});
```

Or you handle each field separately, because in fact they are named different:

```
jQuery("#test_form").validate({
    rules: {
        'floor[abc]':{
            required:true
        },
        'floor[cde]':{
            required:true
        },
    }
});
```

Or you rename your fields:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="floor[][abc]" type="text" class="input_txt_l " value="" />
<input name="floor[][cde]" type="text" class="input_txt_l " value="" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery("#test_form").validate({
    rules: {
    'floor[]':{
        required:true
    }},
});
```

[fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/v8oqqnw4/1/).

Comment: what if only one is mandatory ??

Comment: @Bugfixer I am not sure if I get your question correctly, but in case you have just one exception you could go for something like floor[]:{required:false} and the specific field floor['fieldname']:{required:true}

Comment: I tried this and still not working. But then I figured out that I missed the quote for input field names and it works now. Thanks for this